# how do i wait for a task inside a method before continuing execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, dispatch-async

I have a class (suppose named 'A') that contains a method with `NSURLSessionDataTask`, and a `NSDictionary` property. I am adding the JSON response to a `NSDictionary` property. In my mainViewController i  created an object of class A and called the method. Now in the `mainViewController` i need to access the `NSDictionary` of class A. Now the issue is after the call to the method inside class A, i need to add `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];` before i access the `NSDictionary` or the dictionary is null. I have tried this before accessing the dictionary, but it didn't work

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [requestObject requestAPIMethod];
});

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
// access the dictionary
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

P.S : I have gone through similar questions on SO, but didn't find any clue.

Comment: You should pass a completion handler block to the method in class A. When the response has been retrieved invoke the completion handler with the returned data.

Comment: **Never** sleep in the main thread.  **Never.**

Comment: @Avi I know avi, just wanted to make sure the code run and then look into this. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thank you for the hint, i have written the answer, please let me know if i missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

After spending couple of hours trying to figure things out, i will answer my own question so that newbies like me can benefit. Like Paulw11 mentioned, i used a completion handler block and declared the completion handler block the Class A's `.h` file as:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
```

Then i passed the block to the method as a parameter:

```
- (void) requestAPIMethod : (myCompletion) compBlock;
```

Then in the definition of your method make sure that you do:

```
compBlock(YES);
```

This has to be done after all the processing that you need to do.
Then in my mainViewController.m i created an object of class A, then all the code that was waiting went inside:

```
[classAObject classAMethod:^(BOOL isSuccess) {
if(isSuccess) {
// code that was waiting for the method to complete execution
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps.